# jquery making a checkbox

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a check box by creating a div with an id (check) and class (unchecked);

I created another class(checked) for this div if it's clicked.

Then, I created an input type checkbox to use his attribute checked in order to change my div class from the value of `('my input').is(':checked')` status(*true* or *false*). But the problem is that it works on the 3rd click and on the 4th click nothing happens.

My html code is a div with check as id and unchecked as a class in first time.
my definitions of checked and unchecked is about the backgroud one with an image unckecked and the other is checked

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#check').click(function(){

    var isChecked = $('input[name=it]').is(':checked');

    if(isChecked){
    $( "#check" ).removeClass( "checked" ).addClass( "unchecked" );
     $('input[name=it]').attr('checked', false);

    }
    else{
          $( "#check" ).removeClass( "unchecked" ).addClass( "checked" );
      $('input[name=it]').attr('checked', true);
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: Just curious, what was wrong with the normal `<input type="checkbox" />`?

Comment: Use `.prop` instead of `.attr` and it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for the `input[type=checkbox]` to set status. You can work with one class, and it will do the job. Use Jquery `.hasClass()` selector instead of setting properties. Here's an example:

HTML:

```
<div id="check"></div>
```

JS:

```
$("#check").click(function() {
if($(this).hasClass("checked")) {
        $(this).removeClass("checked");
    }
    else {
        $(this).addClass("checked");
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
#check
{
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background:blue;
}

#check.checked
{
    background: red;
}
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dZfGk/

Comment: thank you, but if i'll have a lot of checkboxes with php depending on my database elements ( my id will be like id="check$var)and var goes from 0 to my number of elements how can it work for them all?

Comment: Then, instead of ids, give the divs a common class, like "checkbox". Then change the $("#check").click() selector for $(".checkbox").click(). Don't worry because it will not interfere with the "checked" class.